# Crystal report related problem on server

Tags: asp.net

I uploaded my project on server then i am facing the following problem, while it does wok fine on local.

> Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

What is this problem please let me know

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
Line 67:   <httpHandlers>
Line 68:   <add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
Line 69:     
Line 70:     <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make you installed the Crystal package on the web server, or include them in your app's bin directory.  Also make sure you installed that same specific 10.2.3600.0 version on the server or you will have to do assembly binding redirects.

Comment: <customErrors mode="Off"/>
   Line 67:   <httpHandlers>
    Line 68:   <add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx"          type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
Line 69:     
Line 70:     <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>

Comment: Can you go to C:\Windows\Assembly\  and see if the Crystal assemblies are listed?